# Not indexing C code include directory

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.5

I have an existing C project and I want to use XCode as my IDE. Just to be clear, I have no intentions of building this on Mac OS X since it's an embedded linux codebase. I really just want an IDE for editing, searching, Jump To Definition, etc. etc. I'm trying to determine if Xcode will work for me.

As an example, I've created a command-line project in Xcode (C++ since there are mixes of C and C++), and added my source tree to the project.

My source tree is such that it appears similar to the following. Please note that my build directory is outside my src directory. src does contain Makefile.in files.

```
src
 |----include
 |      |----file01.h
 |----file01.c
 |----AnotherDirectory
 |      |---file02.h
 |      |---file02.c
```

In XCode 3 the indexing will find definitions in file02.h, but not in file01.h.
In XCode 4 the indexing will not find definitions of anything defined in file01.h or file02.h.

Is there a way to add folders or files to the indexing?

In both version I've added the src folder and linked instead of copied.

Is there a way to get XCode 3 or 4 to be able to Jump To Definition with my source tree?

Regards,
slow-runner

Edit: Explicitly adding the directory "include" did not fix the issue.

Edit02: If I copy as necessary and create folders for groups, it finds everything. However, if I only add references and don't copy the source over into the project workspace folder, it won't find any of those definitions. This seems to point to a referencing issue.

Comment: Have you explicitly added the header files to the Xcode project?

Comment: I guess not. I added the src folder to the project.

Comment: You need to add the headers as well.

Comment: I guess I have a rather stupid question: how do I explicitly add header files? I see I can add files to the project (and that's how I added my source tree), but nothing that is specific to a header file.

Comment: Just add them using that file dialog.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the issue. :-(

Comment: I would have expected that to work; I know it works for my code.

Comment: I notice in your edit you state "... adding the directory...".  How about explicitly adding the header files, as mentioned in my first comment?  Adding the directory might not be the same thing (not sure).

Comment: Good point. I asked earlier how to explicitly add a header file. The recommendation was to add the directory just as I add a file. That is what didn't work. How do I explicitly add an existing header file to a project?

Comment: Simply from the *Add Files to Project...*, select the header files by Cmd-clicking them.

Comment: I also tried that and it did not work.

Comment: I guess Xcode isn't for you then...

Comment: I think I found a way to get it done. It's all in how I setup the project. (Not sure why it is so different). I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I got it to work. I'm not sure why there is a difference, but when I add files to my Xcode project, if I select:

```
Create groups for any added folders
```

instead of

```
Create folder references for any added folders
```

everything get's indexed properly. Nothing gets copied into my source tree. Not sure why this should get indexed differently, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

even when this is an very old problem. I just had the same issue with the current Xcode. A solution that worked for me was to **not** include the **src** folder but its **parent** folder. In my case that was a CMake project folder that, except for a build directory, did not contain much. Even when Xcode does nothing with the CMake files now the **indexing works** otherwise not.